# Keeping cache consistent with a DB

Tags: mysql, caching, transactions, eventual-consistency

We have a large amount of product data that is divided into several MYSQL servers. Each server contains product details per category (Lets call these category DBs), and then there is this one server which contains the high level meta data (Lets call this global DB) of all the products. The UI nodes reside in separate nodes.

The information contained in category DBs is more detailed, like all the info related to a product. The information contained in the global server is very high level information of those product, like the Price, Title and Category. This high level information is also present in the category DBs.

Note: I am open to using any kind of technique to keep this high level global data, be it NOSQL or Relational DB.

Ex:

Global table:

- ProductID
- CategoryID
- Price
- Title

Where as the category DB table would contain a lot more entries, like Description, Location, City, etc, etc, **in addition to the entries in global table**.

So the data in global DB is already present in city DBs, the need to keep it there is for ready reference in case products from different categories are being searched on in one single query. Think of this global DB essentially as a cache of certain fields in the category DB.

If I make changes to Price of a product, I should make changes to both the category and global DB. This is something where transactions would start to cause an issue. And I'm not a fan of XA transactions, having heard so many pitfalls it has, and is slow.

Now I am pretty sure there are a lot of people who have a problem very similar to this one, where caching is involved. The updation may succeed in the category DB, but fail while updating the cache. How do those people manage such situations, and what are the known issues with them? Also, the UI node may keep going up and down, so keeping a state of such info on the UI node itself may cause some problem, so I guess messaging queue can be used to store some state data, that eventually gets to the cache, but I am not sure if thats the way to go.

I am open to any kind of workaround, which would at least eventually take the cache+DB to a consistent state. Please suggest.

## EDIT 1:

I cannot remove the entries from the Global DB for an entry that exists in Category DB. So invalidation of Global DB entry when updating the Category DB is not acceptable. The entry has to always be there. May be use some dirty flag approach?

## EDIT 2:

The entry in Global DB can have a dirty flag, which can be set whenever updates are happening at the Category DB level. However, the issue now would be in inserts, which is when the entry may not get inserted in one of those two DBs. I propose we can potentially get around this problem by using another table in category DB, which stores commands of things to do. So if an insert is made in Category DB, I add a row in this table, with command which says that an entry has to be made into Global DB. Some process has to keep polling this table and execute those commands. This way, the entire thing is transactional, and with slight delay, the insert problem also goes away.

Is it becoming too complex?

Comment: So Global DB is just a cache of category DB?

Comment: Yes, its a cache of all the category DBs. So There could be 3 category DBs, all on their own servers, the global DB will contain high level data for all the products in all those 3 servers

Comment: Well then one classic way of handling cache is : when you update category DB, you *delete* the corresponding cached entry on global DB (not update). Your code trying to fetch the cache from Global DB must handle the situation "cache miss", i.e. when not found, lock, fetch from category DB, insert into Global DB, unlock.

Comment: I unfortunately cannot do that. If the entry is not there in Cache DB, that's an indication that the entry is not there in category DB either. However, what I think can maybe work is to use some sort of dirty flag in Cache DB when updating the Global DB. Do you think that's some thing that may work?

Comment: Wait what is Cache DB? Anyway that's not how cache is supposed to work. If an entry is missing from the cache, it should *not* be an indication that the entry does not exist! Cache is not supposed to be authoritative. That being said, your flag idea could work for updates yes, but then you'll have the problem when inserting.

Comment: Agreed, its kind of 'cache', but with restrictions as I suggested. And I hear what you're saying, that is insertion may be a problem, but can insertion problem be somehow alleviated, ie., can I create a message in MessageQueue, which ultimately gets processed and gets inserted as an entry in Global DB? Basically, a bit of delay in insertion of entry is okay, I hope you see where this is going

Comment: And yeah, the comment should have read as "I unfortunately cannot do that. If the entry is not there in Global DB, that's an indication that the entry is not there in category DB either. However, what I think can maybe work is to use some sort of dirty flag in Global DB when updating the Category DB. Do you think that's some thing that may work?"

Comment: I suppose you could do that. You can also do that for updates and deletes as well, and you could use a third-party queuing system like RabbitMQ for example. But it's hard to say what will be the consequences. You have to make sure that your application is aware that GlobalDB is not authoritative and might be out-of-sync (even if only for a few seconds). If delay is not a problem, then you should be fine.

Comment: Okay. In critical cases, the MQ may also fail. In such cases,we can potentially get around this problem by using another table in category DB, which stores commands of things to do. So if an insert is made in Category DB, I add a row in this table, with command which says that an entry has to be made into Global DB. Some process has to keep polling this table and execute those commands. This way, the entire thing is transactional, and with slight delay, the insert problem also goes away.

Too complex?